# Ternary Operator String Length error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Whats wrong with this

```
ViewBag.description.Length > 160 ? 
    ViewBag.description.Substring(0, 160) : 
    ViewBag.description;
```

gets this error

> An exception of type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of
>   type 'string' and 'int'

but its not a string, because im doing the check on length?

Comment: You proabaly have something on the left of your ternary operator right? I mean, you do assign the value to something right?

Comment: I didnt include it, it says `ViewBag.Meta = ViewBag.description.Length > 160 ? ViewBag.description.Substring(0, 160) : ViewBag.description;`

Comment: May be the ViewBag.description.Length of type string cast it to type int and check

Comment: What are the types of `description` and `Length`, is either of them `dynamic`?

Comment: description is dynamic

Comment: Description may be dynamic, but it must at least have a valid `.Length` property. What *is* that `Length` property, though? Dale - can you put a breakpoint on the line before the exception and check the value of `description.Length`? Specifically: if you print it to the output window, is it wrapped in quotes or not?

Comment: Can you make sure description always contains a string? Like `if(ViewBag.description.GetType() == typeof(string))`

Comment: If you were using ViewModels instead of ViewBag, you won't be having this kind of issues, since Viewbag is of dynamic type... and without a cast you don't have a ".Length" property, as the responses told you. Try to banish Viewbag usage... you will have lot less issues and your code will be strongly typed and you will see compile time errors instead of runtime ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of exception you are seeing is [described on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.runtimebinder.runtimebinderexception.aspx) as:

> Represents an error that occurs when a dynamic bind in the C# runtime
>   binder is processed.

Which indicates that one of your fields is `dynamic`. The exception details specify the `Length > 160` part of your code is causing trouble, and that one of the operands is a `string` while the other is an `int`.

Now here's the fun part about `dynamic` typing; consider I have the following code:

```
dynamic d = 1;
int e = 1;

var length1 = d.Length;
var length2 = e.Length;
```

Where both `e` and `d` hold the same value, but they aren't of the same type. `length1` will compile just fine, and I won't ever figure out that `d` has no `Length` member until runtime, whereas `length2` won't compile at all because `int` has no member named `Length`.

The solution would be to explicitly cast your left and right operands before performing the `<` operation, in this case, casting `ViewBag.description` to string, and calling `.Length` on the result.

Comment: Casting to string isn't necessary if the value is already a string, and will quite possibly fail otherwise. If you use `.ToString()` instead then you risk masking a more complex (and important) issue. I'd say the chances are that `description` *isn't* a string, but that it has a `.Length` member that returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try using explicit casts. In case the `description` is dynamic (as it seems from your exception), you may need to cast it. If the `description` field is of type `string`, you can do this:

```
( ((string) ViewBag.description).Length > 160) 
    ? ViewBag.description.Substring(0, 160)
    : (string) ViewBag.description;
```

I'd do this to make it more readable:

```
var description = (string) ViewBag.description;

ViewBag.Meta = "Text " + (description.Length > 160 
    ? description.Substring(0, 160)
    : description);
```

**Update**. 
As per [@Dale Fraser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640513/dale-fraser)'s comment I added the full assignment according to his code.

I suppose the compiler gets confused when the chunk `"Text " + description.Length` is encountered as it is unable to determine the latter is part of a ternary expression - perhaps it is confused by the dynamic. This could explain the compiler error you get.

The round brackets should fix this, as they will enforce higher priority of evaluation on the ternary operator. The plus operator then will know it is performing string concatenation, as the right operand will be the evaluated ternary operator (which should be a string).

Comment: To me personally, the second one is hardly more readable than the first.. :)

Comment: Something still isn't right 
`var description = (string)ViewBag.description;
                ViewBag.Meta = "Text " + description.Length > 160 ? description.Substring(0, 160) : description;` gets an error Additional information: Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'
`

Comment: @DaleFraser, check my update, now I added braces around the ternary operator.

Comment: Produces the same result

Comment: @DaleFraser, could you give me the line of the error? And, how about this approach: `string desc = (description.Length > 160 ? description.Substring(0, 160) : description);` and then use the `desc` variable: `ViewBag.Meta = "Text " + desc;` or `ViewBag.Meta = String.Concat("Text ", desc);`. If you get the same problem, give me the result of this call: `desc.GetType().FullName;` - if all is OK this should say `System.String`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
 ViewBag.Meta = Convert.ToInt32(ViewBag.description.Length) > 160 ? ViewBag.description.Substring(0, 160) : ViewBag.description;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `ToInt32()` is not a standard extension.

Comment: `description.Length` (string.Length) already returns an integer, why convert?

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg but do you see anywhere that `description` is actually a string? if not one might ask why assume that it is because if it was why would the compiler complain that `description.Length` is a string?